# OpenMDAO Command Line Check Error

Tags: openmdao

> Hi
>
> I receive an error (see below) when i try to do a 'sanity check' to
>   the test -sellar.py. Is this an error connected to the latest version?
>   (2.2.0)  Same error is received when
>
> openmdao -h
>
> openmdao check sellar.py

- I am using Anaconda Prompt with OpenMDAO 2.2.0 and other details:
                platform : win-64
           conda version : 4.3.30
        conda is private : False
       conda-env version : 4.3.30
     conda-build version : 3.0.27
          python version : 3.6.3.final.0

The error : 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "**main**", mod_spec)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\openmdao.exe__main__.py", line 5, in 
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openmdao\utils\om.py", line 15, in 
    from openmdao.devtools.debug import config_summary, tree, dump_dist_idxs
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openmdao\devtools\debug.py", line 8, in 
    from resource import getrusage, RUSAGE_SELF, RUSAGE_CHILDREN
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resource'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in the following recent pull request:  https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/pull/519.  If you pull down the latest version from the master branch it will contain the fix.